# The script isn't working in the following php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My script isn't working which is supposed to add fields about the guest.

The Add more button isn't working

This is for a form to be filled by the guests by using MySQL, PHP, JavaScript,Jquery,AJAX and HTML.

`$(document).ready(function()` => this function seems to not work. I tried checking using alert and it still didn't show any alert message in the browser(both Chrome And Edge).

JAVASCRIPT + JQUERY + AJAX FILE

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  

    alert("Alert me,fksdkf");
    var i=1;

    $('#add').click(function(){

        i++;

        $('#dynamic_field').append('<div class="dynamic-added" id="'+i+'"><div class="container"><div class="col-xs-5">Name Of Occupant <br><input type="text" name="na[]" placeholder="Name" value=" <?php print_r($na); ?>" class="form-control name_list" required="" ><br><br></div><div class="col-xs-3">Relation <br><select class="form-control name_list" value=" <?php print_r($rl); ?>" name="rl[]"><option value="Father" >Father</option>  <option value="Daughter" >Daughter</option>     <option value="Wife" >Wife</option>  <option value="Son" >Son</option> <option value="Mother" >Mother</option> <option value="Sister" >Sister</option> <option value="Brother" >Brother</option> <option value="Friends" >Friends</option> <option value="Cousin" >Cousin</option> <option value="Self" >Self</option> <option value="Other" >Other</option>    </select><br><br>  </div> <div class="col-xs-2"> Age <br><input type="text" name="ag[]" placeholder="Age" value=" <?php print_r($ag); ?>" class="form-control name_list " required="" > <br><br> </div>  <div id="blk" class="col-xs-3"> Block <br> <select name="bl[]" class="form-control name_list" value=" <?php print_r($bl); ?>" onchange="Occupant(this.value)"> <option value="">Select</option> <option value="officer" >Officers Block</option> <option value="jcoblock">JCOs Block</option>  <option value="orBlock" >ORs Block</option>                   </select><br><br></div><div class="col-xs-3" id="dr">Type <br> <select name="type[]" class="form-control name_list" value=" <?php print_r($type); ?>" onchange="rodo(this.value)" > <option value="">Select</option> <option value="r">Room</option><option value="d">Dormitory</option>  </select><br><br> </div> <div class="col-xs-3" id="roo"> Rooms Available<br><select name="room[]" class="form-control name_list" value=" <?php print_r($room); ?>"> <option value="">Select</option> <option id="o1">o1(F)</option> <option id="o2">o2(f)</option> <option id="o3" >o3(f)</option> </select><br><br></div> <div class="col-xs-3" id="doo"> Dormitory  <br> <select name="dorm[]" class="form-control name_list" onchange="bed(this.value)" value=" <?php print_r($dorm); ?>"> <option value="">Select</option><option id="d1">d1(F)</option> <option id="d2">d2(f)</option> <option id="d3" >d3(f)</option> </select><br><br> </div> <div class="col-xs-2" id="doo">           Bed<br> <select name="bed[]" class="form-control name_list" value=" <?ptp print_r($bed); ?>"> <option value="">Select</option> <option id="b1">b1(F)</option><option id="b2">b2(f)</option><option id="b3" >b3(f)</option> </select><br><br> </div><div class="col-xs-4" id="doo">              Bed Charge(per day) <br> <input type="number" name="bcharge[]" placeholder="300" class="form-control name_list" value=" <?php print_r($bcharge); ?>"required="" ><br><br> </div> <div class="col-xs-4" id="doo"> Dorm Electricity Charge (per day) <br> <input type="number" name="dcharge[]" placeholder="10" class="form-control name_list" required="" value=" <?php print_r($dcharge); ?>" ><br><br> </div> <div class="col-xs-4" id="roo"> Room Charge (per day) <br>  <input type="number" name="rcharge[]" placeholder="500" class="form-control name_list" value=" <?php print_r($rcharge); ?>" required="" ><br><br> </div><div class="col-xs-4" id="roo"> Room Electricity Charge (per day) <br><input type="number" name="recharge[]" value=" <?php print_r($recharge); ?>"placeholder="20" class="form-control name_list" required="" ><br><br></div> <div class="col-xs-5" id="doo"> Security Deposit <br><input type="number" name="sec[]" placeholder="300" class="form-control name_list" value=" <?php print_r($sec); ?>" required="" ><br><br></div><div class="col-xs-5" id="doo">Booking Date From  <br>  <input type="date" value=" <?php print_r($bdf); ?>" name="bdf[]" placeholder="300" class="form-control name_list" required="" ><br><br></div><div class="col-xs-5" id="doo"> Booking Date To  <br> <input type="date" name="bdt[]" placeholder="300" class="form-control name_list" value=" <?php print_r($bdt); ?>" required="" ><br><br> </div>  <div class="col-xs-2"><br><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add More</button></div><br><div class="col-xs-2"><br><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">Remove</button></div></div></div>');  

    });


    $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
        $(''+button_id+'').remove(); 
    }); 


    $('#submit').click(function(){            
        $.ajax({  
            url:"addmore.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:$('#add_name').serialize(),
            type:'json',
            success:function(data)  
            {
                i=1;
                $('.dynamic-added').remove();
                $('#add_name')[0].reset();
                        alert('Record Inserted Successfully.');
            }
        });  
    });
});
```

Html code responsible for adding the button

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <br>
    <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add More</button>               
</div>   
<div class="col-xs-2"><br><br>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

Comment: I am unable to see that you have added jquery library in your code. Until jquery library not added, your jquery code will not work. check here:https://jsfiddle.net/gboehp1s/

Comment: Additionally, the problem doesn't seems related to AJAX, PHP, MySQL, ... This is probably a JS, or maybe HTML issue

Comment: First of all, make sure you have the Jquery library connected. Next comment everything else except alert then check it again, if there is any syntax error the entire script will stop running. Also, check for the console in inspect element for any error. Please upload the screenshot of the console.

Comment: I have included jquery library as follows:-                                                      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: I have already added the library you are mentioning

Answer (score 0):

Use this jquery library file link. You can use this library file link your PC or Laptop must be connected on Internet.
else 
you can download the library file and upload locally.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

After successfully include this library file check your jquery code working or not.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

    alert("Alert me,fksdkf");
})
```

Comment: @SayantanChoudhury jQuery library is not working or the code you want is not working ? Have you checked alert code suggested by Arun is working ?

Comment: Press ```ctrl + F5 ```. Because its clear your temp catch. And what kind of error you have got it???

Comment: @RajeshKakkad Yes, I have tried that also but it doesn't give me an alert so i am starting to think that the whole script might not be working!!

Comment: @SayantanChoudhury - make page with this example which only loads jquery and then run alert code there. You will not be able to do anything depending on jquery until you make jquery load properly first. After alert works, build and debug rest of your code : https://gist.github.com/Andrelton/12539cee2ca4ba5fde45

Comment: @SayantanChoudhury : alert example had missing parenthesis which I have added. Alternatively check this bare minimum page I putup for you. After you check alert there, "view page source", use the code for your page. http://pressnote.org/jqalert.htm